# Is this a good (efficient) way to solve this JavaScript exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This is an exercise from FreeCodeCamp and I would like to know if this solution is good enough or I should have solved it in a different way:

**EXERCISE**:

> We have an array of objects representing different people in our contacts lists.
>
> A lookUpProfile function that takes firstName and a property (prop) as arguments has been pre-written for you.
>
> The function should check if firstName is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.
>
> If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
>
> If firstName does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact"
>
> If prop does not correspond to any valid properties then return "No such property"

**SOLUTION:**

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];

// SOLUTION

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
 var checkName = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
  if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
   checkName = contacts[i].firstName;
   break; 
  } else { 
   checkName = "No such contact";
  }
   }
 var checkProp = "";
 for (var j = 0; j < contacts.length; j++) {
  if ((contacts[j].hasOwnProperty(prop)) === true && checkName != "No such contact") {
   checkProp = contacts[i][(prop)];
     break; 
  } else { 
   checkProp = "No such property";  
  }
   }
 
 switch (checkName) {
  case "No such contact":
   console.log (checkName); // I have put there return instead of console.log.
  default:
   console.log (checkProp); // I have put there return instead of console.log.
 }
  
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function

lookUpProfile("Sherlock", "likes");
```

Another important question:
It took me around **2,5 hours so solve this** (I am a beginner and everytime I get to learn loops, I struggle).

Is it normal or should I have found a solution before?

Thank you!! Learning to program is very difficult but rewarding!!

Comment: This should probably be moved to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is an interesting question.  However, this site isn't the best place to ask this sort of question.  Stack Overflow is specifically about code **which is not functional**.  Instead, you should post the question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Opps sorry, didn't even know about the existence of Code Review webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution;

```
const lookup = (firstName, prop) => {
  const person = contacts.find(p => p.firstName === firstName);
  if (!person) {
    return 'No such contact';
  }
  if (!person[prop]) {
    return 'No such property';
  }
  return person[prop];
};


const person = lookup('Kristian', 'likes');
```

Comment: I think it will be `return person[prop]` at the as per OP's requirement

Comment: Again, I think you can directly return `person[prop]`, because you already have checked that `person` and `person[prop]` exists!

Answer (score 0):

Well my solution was valid but I think very complicated and a waste of resources.

A very easy way to solve it is:

```js
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          return contacts[i][prop];
        } else {
          return "No such property";
        }
  }
  
 }
 return "No such contact";
```

Answer (score -1):

A quicker solution would be using the `find` function for arrays. Something like:

```
var person = contacts.find(function(contact) {
   return contact.firstName === firstName;
});
if (!person) {
    return 'No such contact';
}
if (!person[prop]) {
    return 'No such property';
}
return person[prop];
```

It can be hard to learn/know about all of the tools and functions available, but in this case the [find function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is very useful.

As stated in the comments this would be more appropriate for the [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I thought I would give you an answer in the meantime.

Comment: Did you run this code? Filter returns an array so !person will never happend. Are you looking for Aarray.prototyp.find maybe?

Comment: Couple of bugs here -- the filter should be checking `contact.firstName` not `person.firstName`.  `.filter` returns an array, so the later tests should be against `person[0]`(or better should check every item in the person array for a matching `prop`)

Comment: @pethel Thanks for the note. I was intending to reference person[0], but overlooked it. `find` is a better option though, so I've edited my code to reflect this.